# Issue in binding ng-options and ng-model

Tags: html, angularjs, angular-ngmodel, ng-options

I have a web-app where the front-end takes in user input for two field: Day and category and the inputs has to be sent to the backend as a JSON. I am unable to do so.

My code is as follows:

index.html

---

```
<div ng-controller="HomeController">
<p>Day of publishing the article:</p>
<select name="day" id="day" ng-options="day as day.name for day in days" chosen ng-model="formData.day"></select><br><br>
</div>

<div ng-controller="HomeController">
<p>Category of the article:</p>
<select name="category" id="category" ng-options="category as category.name for category in categories" chosen ng-model="formData.category"> </select><br><br>
</div>
```

---

HomeController.js

var myApp = angular.module('myApp.controllers', []);

```
myApp.controller('HomeController', ['$scope','$http',function ($scope,$http) {

    console.log("Hello");
    $scope.formData={};

    $scope.days = [
     { name: 'Monday' },
     { name: 'Tuesday' },
     { name: 'Wednesday' },
     { name: 'Thursday' },
     { name: 'Friday' },
     { name: 'Saturday' },
     { name: 'Sunday' },
   ];    
    $scope.categories = [
     { name: 'Lifestyle' },
     { name: 'Entertainment' },
     { name: 'Business' },
     { name: 'Social Media' },
     { name: 'Tech' },
     { name: 'World' },
   ];   

    $scope.submit = function() {

        $http.post("http://localhost:8080/api/users/", $scope.formData).
        success(
            function(response) {
                console.log(response);
            })
        .error(function(){
            console.log("Error");
        });
    }
}]);
```

[image: Front-end sample]

[image: Sample output]

Comment: What does "I am unable to do so" mean? Does your submit function throw some sort of error? Do you get different data on your server than you are expecting? A bit more detail would help here.

Comment: @Claies: I have a number of inputs from the user on the frontend which are being parsed as a JSON and posted to the backend successfully, except for these two fields I mentioned in the index.html, where I am using the ng-options for drop-down menus. I am adding screenshots of the same in the edited question.

Comment: That still doesn't clarify your problem.  You need to provide your expected and actual results, not just "it wasn't successful".

Comment: {"titleName":"Title","article":"Hello","avgshareArticleShare":3}
So in this JSON the two fields for days and category from my html code are not being parsed. There is no error.

Comment: is that on the server or the client? are you saying that these properties aren't present on your `formData` object?

Comment: This is on the client side and yes that is what I am implying.

Comment: why do you have each of these dropdowns wrapped in their own `ng-controller` instance?  Each of those `<div>` will have a different scope, and that won't work the way you expect.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out, it works after removing the ng-controller instance from the drop downs.

Answer (score 0):

The select dropdowns are wrapped in different instances of the HomeController. Therefore the formData model in both the dropdowns belong to different scopes. I have wrapped the two dropdowns in a single instance of the HomeController.

```
<div ng-controller="HomeController">
   <p>Day of publishing the article:</p>
   <select name="day" id="day" ng-options="day as day.name for day in days" chosen ng-model="formData.day"></select><br><br>

   <p>Category of the article:</p>
   <select name="category" id="category" ng-options="category as category.name for category in categories" chosen ng-model="formData.category"> </select><br><br>
</div>
```

Here is a working [fiddle](//jsfiddle.net/qsc046fy/).